# Elsarticle-harv : \citet{bibid} adding parentheses to year

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

While citing multiple articles, I'm trying to get the following format

> (AuthorsAB, Year; AuthorsCD, Year; AuthorEF, Year)

However, even with using `\citet` command, the output includes parenthesis around the year

> (AuthorsAB, (Year); AuthorsCD, (Year); AuthorsEF, (Year))

As far as I know this shouldn't happen with `\citet`?, any suggestions of how to achieve desired format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You appear to be typing `(\citet{ab,cd,ef})`. Is this correct? Have you tried the `\citep` ("parenthetic style" citation callouts) macro? Please tell us if `\citep{ab,cd,ef}` produces the output you need.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the three bibliographic entries have keys `ab`, `cd`, and `ef`, it appears to be the case that you're inputting

```
(\citet{ab,cd,ef})
```

The reason you're not getting the output you need is that you're using the wrong macro. To create parenthetic-style citation call-outs, you should be using the `\citep` macro, as in

```
\citep{ab,cd,ef}
```

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab, author = "A and B", title = "First  thoughts", year = 3001}
@misc{cd, author = "C and D", title = "Second thoughts", year = 3002}
@misc{ef, author = "E and F", title = "Final thoughts",  year = 3003}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\begin{document}
(\citet{ab,cd,ef})

\citep{ab,cd,ef}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```